# Rails: Rendering a template not showing Instance Variabe values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I'm trying to render a template that sits within another controller in a page. For some reason, the instance variable values aren't showing up in the page where I have the `render`. Although, it does show up when I go to the corresponding HTML page.

I'm pretty new to Rails, and maybe I'm missing something obvious with `render`. Here is some information -

This is the template I have as `template.html.erb`.

```
<a href="http://test.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="panel">
      <div>
        <img src="http://someimage" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <%= @title %>
      </div><div class="text"><%= @text %></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is the corresponding method inside the controller - `content_controller.rb`:

```
def template
   @title = 'Test Title'
   @text = 'Test Content'

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
   end
end
```

I'm trying to render it inside a `page.html.erb` this way -

`render :template => 'content/template`'

I can see the values of `@title` and `@text` if I navigate to `content/template.html` but not when I go to `page.html`

It would be great if somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the route that serves page.html go through the same `template` action as the content/template.html route? If not, that's the problem. The instance variables get initialized in that action, so if page.html doesn't use it, that explains what you're seeing.

Comment: Actually, page.html is inside a different controller. It doesn't go through the template action. Should I call template action from the page action? Sorry, I'm new to Rails. Can you tell me if there is an elegant way to do this?

Comment: You just need to create the same instance variables in whatever controller action precedes the `page.html.erb` template. There are different ways to share the code that does that. But you can just repeat those `@title = ...` and `@text = ...` assignments in page's action.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mori for the answer. Here is what I did -

1. Created a helper method called `get_content` in `content_helper`

   ```
   def get_content
       @title = 'Test Title'
       @content = 'Test Content'
   end
   ```
2. I called the `get_content` method from the page action

   ```
   include ContentHelper

   def page
     get_content
   end
   ```